# Changing my domain name on Google Apps

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-api

I am managing two different email domains using Google Apps: `@domain1.co.za` and `@domain2.com`. I have finally convinced my company that this is impractical as many of the people now have to manage two different emails, and it would make more sense to get rid of the other - that way we also save costs etc.

I now need to transfer everyone on the `@domain1.co.za` to the `@domain2.com`, with their saved email data and their contacts etc. As there are about 700 people needing to be changed over to do this manually will be a very lengthy exercise.

I am hoping there is some sort of API I can use for this?

Answer (score 1):

From [Administrative APIs - Google Apps Administrator Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60757?hl=en)

> Google Apps administrators have access to [Google Apps Administrative
>   APIs](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/). These APIs allow you
>   to collaborate with the Google Apps services using your existing
>   infrastructure. There are a number of administrator and application
>   APIs that can be integrated with Google Apps and the [developer
>   center](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/) has a wealth of
>   information to assist you.

Comment: I have been in contact with google and it seems there isn't a way to directly change the domain name but there may be a way around it, I will post the answer once I have managed to complete the task at hand. I do however thank you for your time, and appreciate the answer.